# Battery drained in overnight

Tags: battery, battery-drain

My new car bedtime t99 battery got drained in overnight now no display all dead, I tried jump start but shows svs light what is it major problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this actually a "Bestune" T99 battery you're talking about? Also, you say it is new. Is it new to you or new/new (like a 2023 model)?